# Android customizing building process

Tags: android

I wish to save the auto-generated resource id in a database at build-time.
How do I capture the generated id, so I can manipulate it?

Example:
I have a layout named main, then android will generate a `R.layout.main` id. I want to capture this id whenever it is generated.

Comment: I don't think this is an Android thing, because the 'R'-class is generated by the adp-tool, which is part of the Android SDK. What do you want to do with the ID, maybe there is another way.

Comment: I am building an application that has a lot of resources. So I have to manage my resources more efficiently. Having the ids in a database makes my life easier...

Answer (score 0):

Default android builds use `ant`. You should search google how to run a script at the end of the build and parse the `R.java` file.

I am more used to maven, and for android you have an excellent [android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/). Doing it in maven should be very easy.

Comment: I'll try using the maven plugin.